# Power Automate Flow Trigger - Microsoft Teams "When keywords are mentioned"

Tags: power-automate

is there a way to get the value of the keyword that is mentioned to trigger the flow?
For example: im using the keyword "Seven", when the keyword is mentioned inside the body of a chat in teams, when it triggered the flow i just wanted to get the keyword "seven" inside the body of chat message and remove other words.

Thank in advance for your help ;)

Here's what i have done so far on my flow:

[Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDIaX.png)

[Flow Continuation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1diKK.png)

this is the output i get from the HTML to text action:

Good Morning! The reports have been uploaded for Group7, thank you!  Below are
the homes that were processed: APPV ARBR BTNY BUEN CDHV CTBT EGER FRVW GNV2 JEWH
KMNJ NGLE OZAN PVAL REGL RRAL RURL SACR SAYR SFLD SHHS SNCH TCST VILL The
following had issues with passwords: APPV RRAL SNCH Please review. Group **Seven**

i want to be able to extract the keyword "Seven" and parse out everything else on the message body.

the purpose is, i will use the keyword seven to trigger another set of flow.
Please note, im using multiple keywords on the trigger action,  i have another set of flow i would like to be able to run depending on the keyword

Comment: Can you provide anything you’ve tried so far?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: My Apologies about that. i edited my question above. thank you for your help.